# Cloud images path and database

Tags: c#, image, onedrive

It is possible an C# form app uploads images using onedrive (or similar) and save it access link in database for future retrieves? I don´t want to save this images as blob on DB...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the [Live SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631819.aspx)
to make a connection with OneDrive. If you need a small [code example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631817.aspx) how to, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can. onedrive well documented with examples, see examples here(C#):
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826531.aspx#uploading_files
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826531.aspx#downloading_files